# How to stop and resume painting in JFrame?

Tags: java, swing

I would like to draw 10 lines in a JFrame. But between the lines I would like to wait for an enter to draw the next line. This code is working for drawing all 10 lines at once:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class TestPaint extends JPanel {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        g.drawLine(100, i*100, 300, i*100);

    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    TestPaint p = new TestPaint();
    f.add(p);
    f.setSize(1000, 1000);
    f.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

Now i tried this but it is not working:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class TestPaint extends JPanel {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        g.drawLine(100, i*100, 300, i*100);
        try {
            System.in.read();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    TestPaint p = new TestPaint();
    f.add(p);
    f.setSize(1000, 1000);
    f.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

What happens is that I press enter 4 times and nothing happens and on the 5th enter all 10 lines appear, which seems very odd.
Now I read that I there might be a thread issue, but I don't know exactly how to achieve what I want.

EDIT: I don't necessarily need to use java. If it is easier to achieve this in another language e.g. python I would also be happy.

Comment: You should create a `List<Line>` and each time an `Enter` is received  add a new `Line` with the next coords to the `List<Line>`.  You really should be playing around with the `paintComponent()` method in that manner.  It is meant to be a quick and easy call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could respond to key events by adding a KeyListener to the panel, and store the currently drawn lines in a list. When the user presses enter, use `list.size()` to modify the x/y coordinates to draw the next line in front of the last one.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class TestPanel extends JPanel {

    public List<Line2D> lines = new ArrayList<Line2D>();

    public TestPanel() {
        this.setFocusable(true);
        this.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
                    lines.add(new Line2D.Double(100, lines.size() * 100,
                            300, lines.size() * 100));
                    repaint();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        for(Line2D line : lines) {
            g.drawLine((int) line.getX1(), (int) line.getY1(), (int) line.getX2(),
                    (int) line.getY2());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        TestPanel p = new TestPanel();
        f.add(p);
        f.setSize(1000, 1000);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Given the flakiness of `KeyListener`, a key binding would be a better solution